Deriving Scale Parameter in Exponential Family
The following is from p. 98 of Casella & Berger's Statistical Inference (2024 edition):

Several of the families introduced in Section 3.3 either are scale families or have scale families
as subfamilies. These are the gamma family if α is a fixed value and β is the scale parameter,
the normal family if µ = 0 and σ is the scale parameter, the exponential family, and the double
exponential family if µ = 0 and σ is the scale parameter. In each case the standard pdf is the pdf
obtained by setting the scale parameter equal to 1. Then all other members of the family can be
shown to be of the form in Definition 3.5.4.

And this is Definition 3.5.4 which appears on p. 97:

Definition 3.5.4 Let $f(x)$ be any pdf. Then for any $\sigma > 0$,the family of pdfs $(1/\sigma)f(x/\sigma)$, indexed by the parameter $\sigma$, is called the scale family with standard pdf $f(x)$ and $\sigma$ is called the scale
parameter of the family.

Because of this, I have been trying to prove that $\mathbf{\theta}$ is the scale parameter for scale exponential family, with its pdf given as $f(x|\mathbf{\theta})=h(x)c(\mathbf{\theta})\exp{\sum_{i=1}^{k}w_{i}(\mathbf{\theta})t_{i}(x)}$ on p. 90. Also from p. 92,

Here $h(x) \geq 0$ and $t_{1}(x), \cdots ,t_{k}(x)$ are real-valued functions of the observation $x$ (they cannot depend
on $\mathbf{θ}$ ), and $c(\mathbf{θ}) \geq 0$ and $w_{1}(\mathbf{θ}), \cdots , w_{k}(\mathbf{θ})$ are real-valued functions of the possibly vector-valued
parameter $\mathbf{θ}$ (they cannot depend on $x$). Many common families introduced in the previous section
are exponential families. These include the continuous families – normal, gamma, and beta; and the
discrete families – binomial, Poisson, and negative binomial.

I have had difficulty to prove this, since there is not so much information about $h(x)$ and $t_{i}(x)$ and whether I can write exponential family pdf as $(1/\sigma)f(x/\sigma)$.
So my question is whether $\theta$ is really the scale parameter for exponential family and if yes, how to prove it based on the definition?

The reference to the exponential family in the first paragraph is specifically to the family of Exponential distributions,  not to the more general definition of "exponential family" you are trying to work with.  I deduce this from the fact that the "gamma family" refers to the specific dist'n, as does the "normal family" and "double exponential family" in the first paragraph, all of which are members of the more general exponential family.  The nomenclature isn't clear, I admit.

A generic exponential family (à la Brown)
$$f(x|{\theta})=h(x)c({\theta})\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{k}w_{i}({\theta})t_{i}(x)\right\}$$
(a) sets no restriction on the dimension of $\theta$ (contrary to Definition 3.5.4 where $\sigma\in\mathbb R^+$) and
(b) sets no restriction on the parameterisation by $\theta$, meaning that any one-to-one transform of $\theta$, $\eta=T(\theta)$ say, can be used instead as its running parameter as in
$$\tilde f(x|{\eta})=h(x)(c\circ T^{-1})({\eta})\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{k}(w_{i}\circ T^{-1})({\eta})t_{i}(x)\right\}$$
which are both sufficient arguments to answer the question in the negative.
I agree that the wording in the first quote of Casella & Berger is unfortunate and should have been

...parameter, the family of exponential distributions, and the family of double exponential distributions...

to avoid the confusion
